# Python - can a Matrix be a variable?

Tags: python, matrix, fortran

I want to convert some Fortran code into Python but there is this block of code:

```
  do i=1,maxcomp
     do j=1,maxcomp
        do k=1,nvbin
           ng(i,j,k) = 0
        end do
     end do
  end do
```

these are do-loops, in Python known as for-loops. The line in the middle (ng(i,j,k) = 0) is a matrix and attached to it is a value, 0 in this case and through the for-loops many "variables" get created and you can refer them with the matrices.

Is there something similar in Python so i can convert the code?

Comment: Everything is a variable!  I think you're looking for either a nested list,  or if you're going to be doing a lot of heavy-lifting with the data, a numpy array.

Comment: If you want to work with matrices in python, you should look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 2):

In Python for 2-dimensional matrices or higher dimensional tensors, the pratic is to use the external package `numpy`. The call `ng=np.zeros((maxcomp, maxcomp, nvbin), dtype='float')` alone will do it for you.

```
!pip install numpy. # will install numpy in virtual environments it is nor present. 
import numpy as np
ng=np.zeros((maxcomp, maxcomp, nvbin), dtype='float')
```

Without resorting to Numpy, there are no native types to represent matrices, but it is easy to customize a class to do so. One of the more intuitive ways is to use nested lists - (also one of the worst ways).
Even dictionaries can work nice as matrices, as long as you control the indices and taking care that they lie inside the desired boundaries.

A dictionary can retrieve a value given comma separated numbers (internally they work as a tuple). So, you can just create an empty dict and use the same code you've seem in Fortran:

```
ng = {}
for i in range(maxcomp):
   for j in range(maxcomp):
       for k i range(nvbin):
           ng[i,j,k] = 0
```

Just take care that dictionaries map arbitrary keys to arbitrary values: they are not constrained to have 3-coordinates mapping to a scalar. But you can create any code you want expecting a dictionary with this structure, and it will work as a matrix (given you pass the sizes for each axis as separate parameters). If the code uses the `.get` method to retrieve values, you do not even need to fill the structure with 0s beforehand: each non-assigned value can be "seen" as 0 in a call like `ng.get((i, j, k), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do matrices, you should do it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
templist = []
for i in range(1,maxcomp):
    for j in range(1,maxcomp):
        for k in range(1,nvbin):
           templist.append([i,j,k])
matrix = np.matrix(templist)
```

Comment: `np.matrix` is being depreciated. you should use an `np.array` instead

Answer (score 1):

using numpy :

```
import numpy as np

ng = np.zeros((maxcomp,maxcomp,nvbin))
```

and probably need to decrease maxcomp and nvbin by 1 , as in python indices start from 0